# Kalki Purana, who actually wrote it?

Tags: puranas, kalki, interpolation, kalki-purana

*Before reading this, I just want to mention that I am a Hindu myself and I have the utmost respect for my Hinduism*

The document called Kalki Puran does not feel real. It almost feels like a hoax. Please hear me and verify it.

There were many yugas and many avatars of Lord Vishnu until today and even though every god and rishis were aware of this, there was no document stating the exact scenario of the future.

For Example: Imagine if Ramayan was written before Ram took birth. Everyone would have known what is gonna happen in detail.
Imagine if Duryodhan knew every single detail of war.

There were prophecies of the 8th son of Mata Devaki but no written documents stating that the 8th son will be tried to kill but escape and grow up in Vrundavan. No future was written.

Not just that but, there are some very disturbing things written like Lord Kalki will kill all the Buddist!? Many times, it is mentioned.
As the Kalki Puran is dated back to Gupta Period, when Buddhism was on the rise, Hindus tried to contain the rise of Buddism by writing Kalki Puran portraying that all those who will follow Buddism will be killed by the Lord Kalki.

There are almost no demi-gods or other significant avatars except Kalki.
Strong powerful demigods have always been present to aid Lord in his mission.

Another thing is rating females by their bodies, this line clearly signifies that Kalki Puran is written in Kalyuga. There are many many incidents in Kalki Puran where the mentioned woman by their well-rounded and shaped breasts!? Whenever a woman of good quality is mentioned, there is mentioning of well-rounded and well-shaped breasts. At the same time, the good physical body features of women are directly attributed to good nature and good qualities. This will clearly mean that females with a small proportion of body features are inferior in every manner.

These are thoughts of a *kaliyugi* man -

I believe that as Buddhism was on the rise in the 6th century, and as everyone was converting into Buddhists, some Hindu people feared, and to save Hinduism and to stop people from converting, they wrote Kalki-Purana which says that all Buddhists will be killed in future by Lord Kalki. Also if you do not know, the real document Kalki-Purana on carbon dating, dates back around the 6th century, precisely the time when Buddhism was spreading like wildfire. Even our great king Ashok Samrat also converted to Buddhism. (the Ashok chakra in our flag is named after him) , so it's clear that a Hindu-dominated area will fear the rise of another religion. And some might have written Kalki Purana and said it's written by Veda Vyasa so that people believe everything is written and start fearing Buddhism.

Not only that but the demon Kali escapes in the end and doesn't die and it is shown that the war is over. But it is not mentioned that Kali died, it's mentioned that he escaped, so while countless Buddist is killed by Kalki, the main person - the Kali demon, escapes!

I am sorry to have hurt your feelings but when reading Kalki Puran, I never felt such a great feeling of enlightenment and life lessons that you get when you read any other Hindu holy book.

I do not hate Hinduism or Kalki Purana, I am a Hindu myself and I respect everything

I learned countless life lessons from Mahabharat, and I learned countless lessons from Ramayan but from Kalki Puran, I didn't feel any extraordinary feeling. And that's why I think it's not actually written by Lord Veda Vyasa but by someone else to actually scare Buddhists as it is written in the 6th century.

So, who actually wrote the Kalki-Purana? Please explain.

Kalki Purana:
https://cloudup.com/cws97nPY2uD

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is opinion based question.

Comment: You're free to do it, but isn't everything opinion based? The 4 vedas, bhagwad gita way of life, everything is opinion based yet people answer it, if you cant answer it fine, but don't divert others into thinking that this is opinion based question

Comment: You know it does not go into enough detail to determine if it Buddhist or followers of Buddha from another activity the Buddha did.

Comment: I am not saying that its written by Buddish people, i am saying it might not be written by Ved Vyas

Comment: First of all Hinduism is cyclic in nature so all scriptures are of the past, present and future. Secondly, the demon Kali is needed and it is a good thing he does not die. Thirdly, why does it matter how the women are portrayed in this puran? Do I need to go on?

Comment: No, you need not to. Because you've explained that you know absolutely nothing and nothing you said is relevant or worth debating about. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

From the way the question is framed, it seems the answer cannot be answered using a scriptural source, or citations acceptable on this platform. Kindly refer to the H.SE Meta on what sources are acceptable [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/who-all-are-authority-or-qualified-to-post-an-authoritative-opinion-on-religion), [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/which-scriptures-sources-are-considered-valid/816#816), and [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/596/what-kind-of-references-are-valid-in-answers-are-modern-works-allowed).

The points made by the OP in the question fall under the domain of Indologists and religious studies scholars, and they will be better suited to answer it from those perspectives.

In any case, the orthodox tradition maintains that the *Kalki-Purāṇa* is not a major *purāṇa*, but a minor or secondary Purāṇa, i.e. an *Upapurāṇa*.

This is what the Mahaperiyavar, Sri Sri Sri [Chandrasekharendra Saraswathi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrashekarendra_Saraswati) MahaSwamiji says -

> [Chapter 6](https://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part14/chap6.htm) - *Upa-puranas and Others*, *Hindu Dharma*.
>
> **Apart from the 18 major Puranas there are an equal number of
> Upapurāṇas. Among them are the Vinayaka Purāṇa and the Kalki Purāṇa.**
> There are also, in addition, a number of minor Purāṇa. The Purāṇa
> that speak of the glory of various months such as the Tula Purāṇa, the
> Magha Purāṇa and the Vaisakha Purāṇa are parts included into the 18
> major Purāṇas or Upa-Purāṇas. There are also what are called Sthala
> Purāṇas, some of them part of the Purāṇas mentioned above and some
> existing independently.

So, as per traditional or *āchāryas* viewpoint, the *Kalki-Purāṇa* is an *Upapurāṇa*, and by definition, and traditional beliefs, the authorship of all the *purāṇas*, be it a major *purāṇa* or a minor *purāṇa*, is credited to the Veda-Vyāsa Kṛṣṇadvaipāyana.

So, to answer the title question - `Kalki-Purāṇa, who actually wrote it?`

The answer is -

- **As per the traditional viewpoint, the  *Kalki-Purāṇa* is compiled by Veda-Vyāsa Kṛṣṇadvaipāyana**.

However, if I may add, the things you bring forth regarding the *Buddhist* influence, and the tone of the language used in reference to women, it may be the case, that the manuscripts of Kalki-Purāṇa we presently have with us, might have been adulterated over a period of thousand many years, and interpolations crept in, in this *Kali-yuga*.

Another important thing that I observed is the lack of the name of the Kalki-Purāṇa in any of the lists found in any *Mahā-Purāṇa* or other text. For instance, the Matsya-Purāṇa [Chapter 53](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.45856/page/n185/mode/1up?view=theater), the Devi Bhāgvatam Purāṇa [1.3](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57102.html), or the Ananda Ramayana - [Sarga 8 - Verse 52-55](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookAnandRamayan/page/n671/mode/2up?view=theater) (Manohar-Kanda), and other texts do not mention the Kalki-Purāṇa in their lists of Upapurāṇas.

In any case, this is just a speculation, for interpolations are almost impossible to prove using traditional & religious inquiry methodologies, and it's not worthwhile to discuss them, as the great Mahaperiyavar says -

> [Hindu Dharma: General](https://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part14/chap4.htm)
>
> There is perhaps an element of the imaginary in the Puranas. **It is
> also possible that they contain interpolations. But who is to
> determine what parts are imaginary and what passages constitute the
> interpolations?** And who is to separate the authentic from the
> spurious? If each one of us removes what seems interpolatory, nothing
> will be left of the stories in the end. So **it would be better to
> preserve the Puranas in the form in which they have been handed down
> to us notwithstanding the apparent errors and distortions.**

---

## To Conclude -

- From the traditional, religious-theological viewpoint, the authorship of the Kalki-Upapurāṇa rests with Veda-Vyāsa Kṛṣṇadvaipāyana.
- It may be the case that the currently extant manuscript of the Kalki-Purāṇa we have with us, might have interpolations and other adulterations but as the great Mahaperiyavar observes that it is not worthwhile to dwell into finding those or ruminating on that facet, but rather gain and focus on the rich spiritual knowledge they teach. If one finds some problems with the text, best to understand it from a qualified guru or *āchārya*, or otherwise, not make much of it if it seems against one's conscience and sensibilities.

Comment: Thank you for answering, it answers almost all of my questions. What i am still in doubt is that, why were there no futuristic puranas in other yugas. Imagine if Shakuni was aware about "Mahabharat" beforehand. Also, Kalki Puran not just subtly suggests but explicitly mentions very disturbing content. I am sure when the great Mahaperiyavar said not to dwell over the interpolations, he meant it in an entirely different aspect. See,

Comment: Because, tons of people due to limited knowledge, doubt things written in ancient texts due to it being scientifically inexplainable. Ultimately, vedas explain almost everything in this universe and time after time it has been proven, but that's not my point.See, there have been plenty of sceptics in this manner and that kind of scepticism is sort if health as it guides one to more knowledge. But, for this very particular case, it seems plausible that Kalki Puran is written with a different intent in Kalyug.

Comment: Is there any evidence to backup the claim other than it being called an Upapuran, to call it a holy and pure religious document written by an extremely knowledgeable sage. Take literally anything else and a different and almost calming feeling will hit you and even if it wont, you will definitely learn something about life. Look at Maryada Purushottam Ram, lord in this avatar teaches us infinite things on how to live. Look at Lord Krishna and Bhagwad Gita 'way of life' as they say. Tell me just one thing that your learned by reading Kalki Puran?

Comment: Instead, there are things like mass slaughter of Buddist people, overly s**ualizing women, etc. Yet again i feel the need of saying that it was written precisely with the aim of stopping that era  Hindus from converting to Buddism. And i see absolutely nothing wrong with it. They tried what anyone would do. Protect our religion. I read Indian history and the time around which Kalki Puran is carbon dated is the exact time when Buddism was spreading very very fast. It spread almost halfway across the globe. Its obvious the other religions would feel threatened and hence, Kalki Puran.

Comment: Atleast that's my perspective, sorry to have hurt anyone's feelings. Thank you and I rest my case

Comment: @Zeke I totally hear you, and understand your concerns, however, the things which you interpret as degrading to the woman-kind are not just limited to the Kalki Purāṇa, but for instance the [Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa Verse 7.1.101.28](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626889.html#note-t-163191) also mentions something to that effect -  “_On seeing an excellent man, the excellent organ of generation of women becomes moistened and dump even if they are observing celibacy or are Yoginīs._"

Comment: Also @Zeke , about Vishnu Killing the Non-Hindus (Buddhas) is something not just limited to the Kalki Purāṇa. For instance, consider the [Chapter 16th of the Agni Purāṇa](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083104.html) where "_Vishnu is said to have born as Buddha and Mahavira to delude demons, and will further kill all the Non-aryans as Kalki_".

Comment: So, it's not like that Kalki Purāṇa has these unique things. More or less all texts might have them. What to a make of it is something I won't comment on, that is a personal viewpoint, but as I quote the Mahaperiyavar, it's pertinent to be like a Swan and drink the ambrosial spiritual Milk from the texts, and leave the watery stuff which you disagree with, out and far. How much you chose to believe in a text is upto you. @Zeke I hope, this clarifies some misunderstandings, if you had before. Thanks and Regards! :) All the Best!!

Comment: Forgive me for beating a dead horse, but the verse you mentioned from Skana Maha Purana isn't degrading women, it's just a biological phenomena mentioned or most a likely a precaution for women practicing celibacy, but that is not my point. Also overly s*xualizing women isn't the only argument i put forth. There are other plenty of compelling evidences point to my matter. At the same time, the verse you mentioned in Agni Puran where Lord Vishnu is said to kill non aryans. Non Aryans mentioned in that context means..

Comment: Non Aryans in that context means the people who have strayed from the path of good and god. People who have become evil in Kalyuga and have strayed far from pro aryan activities. People who lie, cheat, etc, is what they mean by non aryans. The English translation simplifies it to the point where the actual point almost loses its significance. While in Kalki Puran, there are some negative topics unique to it. Also other arguments which i have presented in original question are nowhere else to be found. And to add to "leaving watery stuff which i disagree with, out and far",..

Comment: All I see is watery stuff, If you were able to grasp ambrosial spiritual milk, please shed some light on enlightening life lessons mentioned in Kalki Purana. I do not intend to sound sarcastic, i actually mean it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First off it is unlikely to mean Buddhist, as the time frame is simply too far into the future to reasonably be Buddhism like anything we are accustomed to. It's like over 400,000 years into the future.

Also, this world doesn't have the illusion of Atheism like we have for some reason, and people can clearly see the supernatural, such as the giant female Rākṣasa that is pretty hard to miss. Thus Buddhism being anything similar to our version wouldn't make sense to people who are aware of actual supernatural events.

Anyway, the narrator of the Kalki Purāṇa is canonically Sūta. So he is kind of the writer of it.

https://cloudup.com/cws97nPY2uD

Comment: Like i said, the events mention exactly whats gonna happen in future, imagine if the kauravas got the document Mahabharats before even beginning the war, similar thing is happening, the events are clearly stated, this is ***, the name of kings, kingdoms etc etc is given. At the same time, good physical body features of women are directly attributed to good nature and good qualities. Which will clearly mean that females with small proportion of body features are inferior in every manner. These are thoughts of a kalyugi man

Comment: These are thoughts of a kalyugi man. I believe that as buddism was rise in 6th century, and as everyone was converting into Buddhist, some hindu people feared and to save hinduism and to stop people from converting, they wrote kalki puran which says that all buddist will be killed in future by lord kalki. Also if you do not know, the real document kalki puran on carbon dating, dates back around 6th century, precisely the time when Buddhism was spreading like wild fire. Even our great king Ashok Samrat also converted to buddism. (the ashok chakra in our flag is named after him)

Comment: , so its clear that a hindu dominated area will fear the rise of another religion. And some might have written kalki puran and said its written by ved vyas so that people belive everything written and start fearing buddism

Comment: I do not hate on hinduism or kalki puran, i am a hindu myself and i respect everything but i just do not feel the overwhelming feeling that i get when i read other things like mahabharat and ramayan

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.