# Is this a hoax or genuine? This claims to be a prediction of Muhammad from hindu scripture but I can't find it

Tags: scripture, history, philosophy, belief, identification-request

[image]

I haven't been able to find the source, so would appreciate it if someone could reference this in hindu literature or prove that it's a hoax. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because He is trying show his religion had to be taken up by the advice tulsi das

Comment: This isn't my religion, I'm trying to get an answer to rebut the claim. Seriously, I need advice from the hindu community to know what to say to this claim.

Comment: Apparently the source is Sangram puran skand.12, Khand-6, but I can't find it

Comment: Most likely it's fake.

Comment: That's what I thought, I couldn't find ant source that wasn't the same one.

Comment: 1st of all, i have never heard of any sangram purana. Even if it's there, during tulsi das ji our country was under many Islamist invaders. So, it's not surprising if some islamist cooked up some stories and attributed it under his name. Prd..

Comment: @SriShivaCharanamDasaVishnu could it be referring to sangam literature, I think there are some poems called purananuru

Comment: When Buddhism and Jainism, which are foretold to have been propagated by the avatarams of Sri Hari Vishnu bhagwaan ji himself are considered anti vedic, then what to say about a random religion started by some random person from the middle east? obviously Islam is not vedic in any way and is to be rejected by anyone who is born as or  identifies as a Santan Dharma adherent. Any claim by anyone to call Islam as a true religion for Hindus has be considered as anti reason and false.

Comment: @Draupadi thanks. It mentions Shankarji, from what I understand that's Shiva, right? If so, what era of timr would Shankarji's writing be in?

Comment: Yes Sri adi shankar is sri rudr mahadev ishvar ji himself. He would have lived anywhere between some unfixed date between bce era to 600 ad ce era depending upon the dating method. But that does not matter. What matters is Islam or any other non vedic religion or cult is to be rejected by us Hindus even if allegedly said to be promoted by a Hindu god.

Comment: @Draupadi thanks. Also, you said this, 'When Buddhism and Jainism, which are foretold to have been propagated by the avatarams of Sri Hari Vishnu bhagwaan ji himself are considered anti vedic,'. I've not heard if this before, do you mind explaining this in more detail?

Comment: See this Question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43721/is-it-possible-that-avatars-can-be-anti-vedic And answers in it @sam

Comment: @Draupadi I see, thanks. When you say 'foretold', do you mean that Hinduism predicted hinduism and jainism?

Comment: I don't see how this question is too off topic as it is related to hinduism.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's false the only Purana where Muhhamad is supposedly mentioned is Bhaishya Purana which is a later interpolation of that Purana. I will find verses when I get home and update the answer.

UPDATE: Couldn't find a full version of the PDF, however here are two sources: https://www.stephen-knapp.com/mohammed_is_he_really_predicted_in_bhavishya_purana.htm
http://krizna.in/001-Epics/Bhavishya-Puran-English/Bhavishya-Puran-English.pdf

Shri Suta Gosvami said: In the dynasty of king Shalivahana, there were ten kings who
went to the heavenly planets after ruling for over 500 years. Then gradually the morality
declined on the earth. At that time Bhojaraja was the tenth of the kings on the earth.
When he saw that the moral law of conduct was declining he went to conquer all the
directions of his country with ten-thousand soldiers commanded by Kalidasa. He crossed
the river Sindhu and conquered the Gandharas, mlecchas, shakas, Kashmiris, Naravas, and Sathas. He punished them and collected a large amount of wealth. Then the king
went along with Mahamada (Mohammad), the preceptor of mleccha-dharma, and his
followers to the great god, Lord Shiva, situated in the desert. He bathed Lord Shiva with (Suggest reading the full version, but be wary this is a touchy subject and may leave some viewers emotional or disturbed. The authenticity of this Purana is to be questioned, however.)

UPDATE: The Sangram Purana may not even be real or be another name for the Bhaishya Purana and Tulsidas certainly didn't write about him. How interesting that someone likely fabricated this whole thing. The caption also seems to be referring to a different text.

Comment: thanks. Do you mind expanding on the supposed text from tulsidas though, why it is unreliable etc?

Comment: Because Muhhomad wasn't known and certainly wasn't worshipped in regards to Hinduism. Also Tulsidas was a Rama bhakta, not Muhhomad Bhakta. Let me find the actual verses to this text.