# Can anyone find an english translation of this reference, Sangram puran skand.12, Khand-6?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, translation-request, reference-request, tulsidas

I came across an article that gave this reference, but when I've searched it up, I've only seen the same source. Does anyone have an enligh translation of it, if it exists?

Apparently, it's been translated by Tulsidas. If anyone needs me to give the link, just ask.

Comment: Do you have the original verse?

Comment: @CDR its here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/57186/is-this-a-hoax-or-genuine-this-claims-to-be-a-prediction-of-muhammad-from-hindu?noredirect=1#comment172383_57186